# node.js glob pattern for excluding multiple files

Tags: node.js, glob

I'm using the npm module [node-glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

This snippet returns recursively all files in the current working directory.

```
var glob = require('glob');
glob('**/*', function(err, files) {
    console.log(files);
});
```

sample output:

```
[ 'index.html', 'js', 'js/app.js', 'js/lib.js' ]
```

I want to exclude **index.html** and **js/lib.js**.
I tried to exclude these files with negative pattern **'!'** but without luck.
Is there a way to achieve this only by using a pattern?

Comment: Use `ignore` option. `!` is deprecated in node-glob patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or without an external dependency:

```
/**
    Walk directory,
    list tree without regex excludes
 */

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var walk = function (dir, regExcludes, done) {
  var results = [];

  fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
    if (err) return done(err);

    var pending = list.length;
    if (!pending) return done(null, results);

    list.forEach(function (file) {
      file = path.join(dir, file);

      var excluded = false;
      var len = regExcludes.length;
      var i = 0;

      for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (file.match(regExcludes[i])) {
          excluded = true;
        }
      }

      // Add if not in regExcludes
      if(excluded === false) {
        results.push(file);

        // Check if its a folder
        fs.stat(file, function (err, stat) {
          if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {

            // If it is, walk again
            walk(file, regExcludes, function (err, res) {
              results = results.concat(res);

              if (!--pending) { done(null, results); }

            });
          } else {
            if (!--pending) { done(null, results); }
          }
        });
      } else {
        if (!--pending) { done(null, results); }
      }
    });
  });
};

var regExcludes = [/index\.html/, /js\/lib\.js/, /node_modules/];

walk('.', regExcludes, function(err, results) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: I certainly like the idea of avoiding unnecessary external dependencies, but this snippet has redefined my scale of "worse things people never should have written". To the novice, if you you are not sure how to do the thing properly, then use an external dependency.

Answer (score 74):

I suppose it's not actual anymore but I got stuck with the same question and found an answer.

This can be done using only `glob` module.
We need to use [options](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#options) as a second parameter to `glob` function

```
glob('pattern', {options}, cb)
```

There is an `options.ignore` pattern for your needs.

```
var glob = require('glob');

glob("**/*",{"ignore":['index.html', 'js', 'js/app.js', 'js/lib.js']}, function (err, files) {
  console.log(files);
})
```

Comment: Thanks - very useful because I'm using a library that uses node-glob. No way for me to use any of the other solutions.

Comment: any idea why `{"ignore": ['*dex*']}` does not ignore `index.html`?

Answer (score 47):

Check out [`globby`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby), which is pretty much [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) with support for multiple patterns and a Promise API:

```
const globby = require('globby');

globby(['**/*', '!index.html', '!js/lib.js']).then(paths => {
    console.log(paths);
});
```

Comment: this is pretty much just glob with support for multiple patterns (not node-glob which is a dead end no downloads no readme module)

Comment: `globby` is basically vanilla on top of the awesome `glob` library.. Not that really useful.

Answer (score 18):

You can use [node-globule](https://github.com/cowboy/node-globule) for that:

```
var globule = require('globule');
var result = globule.find(['**/*', '!index.html', '!js/lib.js']);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I wrote for my project:

```
var glob = require('glob');
var minimatch = require("minimatch");

function globArray(patterns, options) {
  var i, list = [];
  if (!Array.isArray(patterns)) {
    patterns = [patterns];
  }

  patterns.forEach(pattern => {
    if (pattern[0] === "!") {
      i = list.length-1;
      while( i > -1) {
        if (!minimatch(list[i], pattern)) {
          list.splice(i,1);
        }
        i--;
      }

    }
    else {
      var newList = glob.sync(pattern, options);
      newList.forEach(item => {
        if (list.indexOf(item)===-1) {
          list.push(item);
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return list;
}
```

And call it like this (Using an array):

```
var paths = globArray(["**/*.css","**/*.js","!**/one.js"], {cwd: srcPath});
```

or this (Using a single string):

```
var paths = globArray("**/*.js", {cwd: srcPath});
```

Comment: I get this : `Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never`

Comment: Are you are using TypeScript? Is the error on this line?? `patterns = [patterns];` Can you provide more info on the error message? It looks like yours was cut off in your post.

Comment: Yes using typeScript 2.5.2,  `if (list.indexOf(item)===-1) {` the error is on `item` and here too `list.push(item);`

Comment: Sorry I don't use TypeScript. Does anyone else have any idea why @An-droid id getting this error?

Comment: You can force any type to conform by converting it to unkown first: `if( list.indexOf( item as unknown as any ) === -1 )`. However, this should only really need to be done in some very specific circumstances. I'd take another look at how you're type-specifying your arguments/parameters and see if there isn't an illogical assignment.

Answer (score 1):

A samples example with gulp:

```
gulp.task('task_scripts', function(done){

    glob("./assets/**/*.js", function (er, files) {
        gulp.src(files)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))
            .on('end', done);
    });

});
```